# Extremely poor performance when launching script through PM2 on raspberry pi

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, raspbian, pm2

I am experiencing a strange error whereby if I launch a node JS script through pm2 I get extremely poor performance and it crashes relatively quickly. This is the error I got:

```
/home/pi/.pm2/logs/app-error.log last 15 lines:
0|scripts | { TimeoutError: Navigation timeout of 30000 ms exceeded
0|scripts |     at Promise.then (/home/pi/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/LifecycleWatcher.js:106:111) name: 'TimeoutError' }
```

The command I use to launch it through pm2 is `pm2 start <script name>` This is my first time using pm2, so I may be doing it wrong, but I am not passing any extra options when launching it through pm2, hence my confusion.

I normally run this script through tmux by using `node <script name>` and it runs perfectly fine, but I needed a solution that would auto restart the script if it crashed for whatever reason.

When monitoring the Pi's usage through `top` it is normally around 40%-60% CPU usage, however, when launched through pm2 it is at less than 10%.

This issue only happens on my raspberry pi. i do not get any problems when running the exact same script on my desktop running windows 10.

Comment: You could just use Raspbian's systemd to restart the script if pm2 is giving you trouble.

Comment: I had not previously heard of systemd, but upon researching systemd, it seems that it is only used to restart a process on reboot and not if the script itself crashes?

Comment: If your unitfile has e.g. [`Restart=on-failure`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Restart=), systemd restarts the unit if it dies unexpectedly.